# DOM ul element, how to create it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have this element at `index.html`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

How can I write a query to get that DOM element?
And create a new UL element and append it to the previously mentioned `<div>` element?

Like here:

```
function displayUsers(users) {
  // ??????????
};
```

I have this element at `index.html`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

How can I write a query to get that DOM element?
And create a new UL element and append it to the previously mentioned `<div>` element?

Like here:

```
function displayUsers(users) {
  // ??????????
};
```

I have this element at `index.html`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

How can I write a query to get that DOM element?
And create a new UL element and append it to the previously mentioned `<div>` element?

Like here:

```
function displayUsers(users) {
  // ??????????
};
```

I have this element at `index.html`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

How can I write a query to get that DOM element?
And create a new UL element and append it to the previously mentioned `<div>` element?

Like here:

```
function displayUsers(users) {
  // ??????????
};
```

Comment: What did you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const ul = document.createElement('ul')
const li = document.createElement('li')
const textNode = document.createTextNode('some text')
li.appendChild(textNode)
ul.appendChild(li)
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(ul)
```

an example here
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: I'm getting an error:
Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

Comment: @freedomn-m well why should I answer it in jQuery? which isn't even the original language. I don't get the idea. I think it's irrelevant comment on this question.

Comment: @mafangulo try the code again i made a mistake. i fixed it.

Comment: The issue was `ul.appendChild(ul)` which does not make sense. it had to be `ul.appendChild(li)`

Comment: @freedomn-m Disagreed. The DOM API is so much cleaner and jQuery has been a thing of the past for 6-7 years now.

Comment: @freedomn-m Why didn't you answer it then? I don't get this debate lol.

Comment: Don't see how jQuery is any simpler than `document.getElementById('app').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<ul><li>one<li>two</ul>")` (although any approach involving generating strings of HTML in JS is likely to be hard to debug compared to the traditional DOM approach in this answer).

Comment: (cleaned up my comments irrelevant to the question/answer)

Comment: @artemismars care to help with another one? I need to create 7 inside the same function that I had before with the code you provide me.
Thing is, how can I add those li elements if I already declared them before?

This is what instruction says:
1. Create a new li element for each item in the users array.
2. Append each created li element to the existing unordered list.
3. Set the string value of each array item as the content of each li element.
Thanks a lot.